# How to random only on 10 first recents posts?

Tags: wordpress, random, pagination

I am facing of a client request, he has 100 products with pagination ( 10 per page), he wants only random on the first 10 products and for the rest of the pages no random ( for others paginations other than 1 )

I have this query :

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array('products'),
    'paged'=> ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1 ),
);
$products = new Wp_Query($argss);
... Loop here ...
... End loop ...
... Pagination ...
```

Products displays well, pagination works, only i ask myself how to achieve this goal. If i use :

```
if( $paged == 1 ) $args['orderby'] = 'rand';
```

It will random on the first page but he will pick other products other than the first 10 product, the goal is to only random the first 10 products on home search page without picking up the others.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: maybe `shuffle` on `$products ->posts` if it's first page?

Comment: Yeah, great idea, i tested it but how to add it to the loop?

Comment: Sorry i get it working with your solution, i don't need to have an headache with the loop, just shuffle( $products->posts ); after the Wp_Query($args);
THANK YOU MAAAN, YOU SAVED MY DAY

Comment: @user4431 you're welcome. I'll post it as answer so that you can accept it and people know that your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

```
if(get_query_var( 'paged', 1 )==1)
{
    shuffle($products->posts);
}
```

after `$products = new Wp_Query($argss);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

if page is 1 then set `'order' => 'rand'`

```
     $args = array(
            'post_type' => array('products'),
            'paged'=> ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1 ),
            'order_by' => 'ID',
            'post_status'=> 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
        );

        if($args['paged'] == 1){
            $args['order'] = 'rand';
        } else{
          $args['order'] = 'DESC';
        }
        $products = new Wp_Query($args);
```

Comment: Thank your, but it will pick up others products from others pages, it consists only to random first 10 product on first page.